# Cannot import package from a different folder

Tags: python, python-2.7, package, python-import

I am working on a project based on Python 2.7 and I am trying to import a module which is in a package folder that contains `__init__.py` and the file that I want to import called `package1.py`, but I am unable to do so. This is my folder structure: `main_project/Tools/common/package1.py`

Note that my project files are in the folder main_project. So, I am trying to call the `package1.py` by using an `import` statement in my script:

```
from Tools.common.package1 import variable
```

But I am getting an `ImportError: No module named Tools.common.package1`.

What is the solution to solving this error as I want to use the package feature for my project?

Comment: Your directory structure is unclear. Please [edit] your question and try formatting the layout as an indented list of file and folders starting from the root.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe use the solution i found here :

```
# some_file.py
import sys
# insert at 1, 0 is the script path (or '' in REPL)
sys.path.insert(1, '/path/to/application/app/folder')

import file
```

or verify your module has a  `__init__.py`

[Importing files from different folder](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4383571/importing-files-from-different-folder)

Comment: This solution does not work. My folder common does have the __init__.py.

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have found the answer. I also had to insert an **init**.py in the folder Tools as well. Initially I only inserted **init**.py in common but not in Tools as we should also make Tools a package if we want to access common